# Convert .txt files into .xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for code or a way to convert a txt file into xlsx as my current txt files are over 2 million lines. I am unable to download any software as or upload the files onto an online converter. I have limited access to coding programmes so this has to be done via standard excel functionality or VBA. The txt file which will be imported is set out into over 120 tables so if the file can be split at the 1 million that would work well. I have searched around online so I'm not sure if this is actually possible

Comment: You can use powerquery for this !

Comment: Look at using ADO to read the files, or TextStream, then loop through the row count you want to split, say every 100,000 per sheet or workbook.

Comment: You say the text file contains 120 tables.  Can these tables be easily distinguished by a macro? For example, if there no blank lines within a table but there are blank lines between tables, a macro could easily separate out the tables.

Comment: Do the tables have a consistent style?  For example: one line containing table name, one line containing column headings then one or more data lines.  Note: the tables do not have to contain the same number of columns.

Comment: Could you write a simple list of instructions for the conversion for someone that does not get bored with repetitive tasks, obeys instructions explicitly but does not show any initiative?  If yes, you can do this with VBA.